# How to change the background of submenu items in actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, submenu

I have added submenu with the below code

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


                SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("user");

                subMenu1.add(0, 3 , 0, "Log out");

                MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();

                subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);



        return true;
    }
```

I have been trying to change the background of the submenu with no luck and I almost covered every post, but no use. The thing is when user clicks on `usermenu`, he gets **logout**  option which is a submenu as in the above code. When submenu drop down is visible on the screen it is looking similar to my activity's background color which is barely visible. I can't change my activity's background color. It should be snow white and even the background color of submenu drop down is snow white by default. So can some one help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit and change the style (abs_style.xml) of the dropdown menu in the ActionBarSherlock library project?

The theme Theme.Sherlock uses all the styles which is present in abs_style.xml.

Comment: I gotta work it in another day. Can you please guide me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196324/changing-the-background-of-the-action-bar-item-in-actionbarsherlock)? It's urgent to achieve this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="Theme.Sherlock.lionbench" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.lionbench.actionbar</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu.lionbench</item>
    <!-- Internal -->
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu.lionbench</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.listPopupMenu.lionbench" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selector_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/selector_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu.lionbench" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selector_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shape_actionbar_popupmenu_bacground_darker_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```